# Error: Non-zero exit from subprocess. Ionic

Tags: capacitor, ionic5

I'm trying to generate the Android and Ionic folder and it's giving this error:

```
% ionic cap add ios
Error: Non-zero exit from subprocess.

at Integration.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/lib/integrations/capacitor/index.js:46:27)
at async AddCommand.getInstalledPlatforms (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/commands/capacitor/base.js:117:21)
at async AddCommand.installPlatform (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/commands/capacitor/base.js:239:36)
at async AddCommand.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/commands/capacitor/add.js:41:9)
at async Promise.all (index 0)
at async AddCommand.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/lib/command.js:81:9)
at async Executor.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/lib/executor.js:54:9)
at async Executor.execute
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/node_modules/@ionic/cli-framework/lib/executor.js:70:13)
at async Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/index.js:110:9)
```

I already reinstalled Ionic, Cap, Cocoa Apds and it didn't solve

Answer (score 16):

This error is caused by the latest version of ionic, please try to downgrade it

```
npm i -g @ionic/cli@6.20.1
```

Comment: after 2 days I found this solution :) Thanks